# Puppet Copy msi, install and delete once

Tags: puppet

I have a question about Resource Type File and Package.

1. I copy msi file from Ubuntu to Windows machine via File-RT (I dont have samba-share)
2. I install the msi file via Package-RT
3. I delete the msi file with Exec-RT

it works so far but my problem is when I call puppet agent --test on the client the msi file will be copied to Windows and after that will be removed.

So my question is: is there a way after copy, install and delete to ignore copy file again to the machines?

thanks in advance

**UPDATE::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

```
  #Copy file to Windows Client
  file { 'copy_msi_file_to_win_client':
          source => "puppet:///modules/test_msi/test.msi",
          ensure => 'present',
          path => "C:/test.msi",
          source_permissions => ignore,
          require => Exec['test'],
  }


  #install TEST on Windows Client
  Package { 'TEST APP NAME':
          ensure   => 'installed',
          provider => 'windows',
          source   => "c:/test.msi",
          require => File['copy_msi_file_to_win_client'],
  }


  #Remove test.msi file
  exec { 'remove_test_msi_file':
          command   => 'Remove-Item c:/test.msi -Force',
          onlyif    => 'if(Get-Service "TEST_SERVICE_NAME") { exit 0 } else { exit 1 }',
          provider  => powershell,
  }
```

Best Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Puppetlab's rsync module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rsync)?

Depending on how you've implemented the copy you can either have an **if** statement checking if the file is in the path, if it's not then run your copy.

If you're using **exec** then you could use 'onlyif' which you can write a powershell or *nix command that will return a boolean and if the boolean is false then the exec will not be run

Comment: thanks for your answer Jackson Lloyd.

I didnot use rsync but Ill test that too.

Can you maybe tell me how to use the if statement in a class?

Here I use now the EXEC but How can I make a relation between EXEC and FILE, as you said we can say EXEC if is 0 then SKIP or dont run FILE ResourceType.

Ill Update my post to put my code there.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" that, I copy the msi file every time to C:\Windows\Temp and I'll later try to solve it better.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly isn't the "Puppet" way to do things. Puppet is a declarative language, so it's trying to keep the server in a particular state; it's not an orchestration tool, which is what you are trying to do here.

That said, I think the only way you are going to get around this is by setting a facter variable on the host. That will get returned before the manifest is applied on the second go around. That file, you will want to add after the "remove-item" command. I think even on Windows, that file, can simply be "MY_FILE_HAS_BEEN_APPLIED=true". After that, simply place some conditional logic in your manifest, something like "if ($facts['MY_FILE_HAS_BEEN_APPLIED'] != true) { everything goes here }", you'll be good to go.

Happy puppeting!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep your nodes clean of installation media. You can use the chocolatey puppet module and deploy your own internal nuget server. Or maybe Puppet already supports **file** resource with a **url**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this using the [`transition` module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/transition). Something like this:

```
transition { 'install media':
  resource => File['C:/test.msi'],
  attributes => {
    'ensure' => 'present',
  },
  prior_to   => [
    Package['TEST APP NAME'],
  ],
}

file { 'C:/test.msi':
  ensure => 'absent',
  source => "puppet:///modules/test_msi/test.msi",
}

package { 'TEST APP NAME':
  ensure   => 'installed',
  provider => 'windows',
  source   => "c:/test.msi",
  require  => File['C:/test.msi'],
}
```